# DBUnit Referential integrity constraint violation one to one relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

I'm writing tests for my repositories and I want to prefill my test H2 database with some data.

```
<dataset>
    <car
            id = "carId"
            name = "some name"
    />

    <user
            id = "userId"
            first_name = "Firstname 1"
            car_id = "carId"
            created_date = "2020-06-23 10:00:00.000"
            last_modified_date = "2020-06-23 10:00:00.000"
    />

</dataset>


@Entity(name = "user")
public class UserEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private CarEntity car;
}

@Entity(name = "car")
public class CarEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String id;
    private String name;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "car")
    private UserEntity userEntity;
}
```

So a car and a user has a one on one relationship.

When I run this I get this error:

```
org.dbunit.DatabaseUnitException: Exception processing table name='user'
    at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractBatchOperation.execute(AbstractBatchOperation.java:240) ~[dbunit-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79) ~[dbunit-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.setupOrTeardown(DbUnitRunner.java:183) ~[spring-test-dbunit-1.3.0.jar:na]
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:75) ~[spring-test-dbunit-1.3.0.jar:na]
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:185) ~[spring-test-dbunit-1.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:289) ~[spring-test-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeEach(SpringExtension.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$1(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:161) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$5(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:197) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:197) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:160) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71) ~[junit5-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK50YE93XM2IW5TTGIDH543NRYV: PUBLIC.USER FOREIGN KEY(CAR_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.CAR(ID) ('carId')"; SQL statement:
insert into USER (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PASSWORD, TYPE, STATE, CREATED_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, CAR_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23506-200]
```

Comment: You have defined your ids as UUIDs and your dataset is providing arbitrary strings.Try using UUIDs for your ids in your dataset. My guess is that Hibernate is creating an H2 UUID type for your ids.

Comment: Still gives me the same problem